# If cell contains a specific value from a Column, show a third cell value

Tags: excel, vba

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have 2000 order numbers in A:A, examples:

```
125787
358946
358961
```

I have 2000 strings that include these order numbers in B:B, examples:

```
12542-MARLBORO-125787
19009-BRYN ATHYN-358946
21037-EDGEWATER-358961
```

I have 3000 person names in C:C that are associated whit the cities listed in column B, examples:

```
Frank Smith - MARLBORO
John Park - BRYN ATHYN
Kevin Decker - EDGEWATER
```

I want to match/find the order numbers from A:A in B:B and return the person's name (in C:C) that is associated to that city and put the name in a new column D:D. I hope this make sense...

Comment: So you want the name in D for the order number in A?

Comment: Yes! base on the match from A:A and B:B....

Comment: What have you tried?  Does it it have to be VBA?  You should be able to use `Find` to get from `A->B->C`.  You can also do this with formulas, again with `FIND` and an array formula.  The real question is... is the mapping from City to Person unique?  If not, that will be the hard part to resolve.

Comment: Byron- I have tried:

Comment: =INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,B:B,0)) but this does not work because for example:  is trying to match order: 125787 with 12542-MARLBORO-125787, is not actually searching to see if 125787 exist on 12542-MARLBORO-125787

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just a formula. In D1, enter

```
=IF(A1<>"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(CONCATENATE("*",A1),B:B,0)),"")
```

Comment: A little explanation and a couple line breaks would improve this answer.

Comment: You could add them here just to help. Excel allows a return character if you paste it in from elsewhere. You can also hit ALT+ENTER, IIRC.

Comment: Byron That code (=LEFT) did not worked. I get "#VALUE!" in D:D

Comment: There is no D:D in the formula I provided. Unless you are dragging it to another column. If you need it in another column, paste the formula from above, and then you can drag down to all rows.

Comment: I pasted the formula in D1 and dragged down to all rows

Comment: This is how it looks like: A1:125787 B1:12542-MARLBORO-125787 C1:Frank Smith D1:#VALUE!

Comment: According to your question, C1 should be 'Frank Smith - MARLBORO', not 'Frank Smith'

Comment: No Sir! I corrected that above... Sorry for that. I was just trying to say... For example that 'Frank Smith' belongs to 'MARLBORO'. Column C:C should only contain names (Frank Smith, John Park, Kevin Decker, etc...)

Comment: Then it's quite simple. In D1: =IF(A1<>"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(CONCATENATE("*",A1),B:B,0)),"")

Comment: **Excellent** use of `MATCH` with a wildcard.  It's so easy to forget that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a button click event that will do what you are looking for.  You will need to add a reference for the adodb recordset.  In the VBA IDE, go to the tools pull down menu - References.  Select the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library".

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim strCity As String
Dim strName As String
Dim iIndex As Integer

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.  You can store sums here.
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "Row", adChar, 20
        .Fields.Append "ColumnB", adChar, 70
        .Fields.Append "ColumnC", adChar, 70
        .Open
    End With

    lRow = 1

    'Loop through and record what is in the columns we want to look at
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields("Row").Value = lRow
        rs.Fields("ColumnB").Value = ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value
        rs.Fields("ColumnC").Value = ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value
        rs.Update

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

    If rs.EOF = False Then
        rs.MoveFirst
    End If

    'Now go through and check the values of the second column against what we recorded from the first
    lRow = 1
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        'Find the record with this order number.
        rs.Filter = ""
        rs.Filter = "ColumnB Like '%" & ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value & "%'"
        If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
            strCity = rs.Fields("ColumnC").Value
            iIndex = 0
            iIndex = InStr(strCity, "-")
            If iIndex <> 0 Then
                strCity = Right(strCity, Len(strCity) - iIndex)
            End If
            iIndex = 0
            iIndex = InStr(strCity, "-")
            If iIndex <> 0 Then
                strCity = Left(strCity, iIndex)
            End If

            'Now find the record with that name
            rs.Filter = ""
            rs.Filter = "ColumnC Like '%" & Trim(strCity) & "%'"
            If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
                strName = ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value
                iIndex = 0
                iIndex = InStr(strName, "-")
                if iIndex > 0 then
                    ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = Trim(Left(strName, iIndex - 1))
                else
                    ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = "not found"
                end if
            End If
        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop
End Sub
```

Per the posters comments on what is desired. Let's see if this works.

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim strCity As String
Dim strName As String
Dim iIndex As Integer

Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.  You can store sums here.
With rs
    .Fields.Append "Row", adChar, 20
    .Fields.Append "ColumnB", adChar, 70
    .Fields.Append "ColumnC", adChar, 70
    .Open
End With

lRow = 1

'Loop through and record what is in the columns we want to look at
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("Row").Value = lRow
    rs.Fields("ColumnB").Value = ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value
    rs.Fields("ColumnC").Value = ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value
    rs.Update

    lRow = lRow + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
Loop

If rs.EOF = False Then
    rs.MoveFirst
End If

'Now go through and check the values of the second column against what we recorded from the first
lRow = 1
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Find the record with this order number.
    rs.Filter = ""
    rs.Filter = "ColumnB Like '%" & ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value & "%'"
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("ColumnC").Value
    End If

    lRow = lRow + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: line: ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = Trim(Left(strName, iIndex - 1))

Comment: Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: What is the value of iIndex at the time it fails?  I made a change to that section to account for not finding a record with that city.

Comment: I step into the code but, I'm not sure how to find the value you want... Sorry! Did you created a workbook/sheet whit 3 rows and columns whit the values I specified above and tested your code? Do you get the same result?

Comment: I did create it and i did not get the error.  Have you tried it with the fix from above?  if iIndex > 0 then and the next 5 lines.

Comment: I ran it, this time I get no errors but I get "not found" in column D. Like: A:125787  B:12542-MARLBORO-125787 C:Frank Smith D:not found

Comment: if C is not "Frank Smith - MARLBORO" then there is no way to match MARLBORO from B.

Comment: Matthew I really appreciate your time and help on this. Maybe I'm not  explaining myself well enough. All I'm trying to do is this.... If I have the following Columns (ColumnA:125787, ColumnB:12542-MARLBORO-125787, ColumnC:Frank Smith). If ColumnB contains the value of ColumnA (in the case the value is

Comment: 125787 which is the last number in the string) then, display the value of Column C in Column D.

Comment: @elyoe011 Try the second set of code. Maybe i over complicated it.

Comment: Happy to help.  Good luck on your future coding.